# Panda-struck Diagnosis

Tags: google-search-console, google-panda-algorithm

I have been reading about the Panda Update going to be on a rollout launch in the year to come. As a webmaster, how do I know for sure that my website has been struck by the Panda update? Does a warning message show up in my GWMT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no warning in GWT specifically.  You may get an unnatural links warning if that is one of your issues but otherwise the penalty is silently applied. You'll know when you get eaten by the Panda because your inbounds from Google will drop like a rock.

Comment: There have been 24 updates to the Google panda update already.  If your site hasn't been effected by panda until now, it is unlikely to be effected by it in the future.

Comment: Panda update today or Monday :P

Comment: @StephenOstermiller If only that were true :)

Comment: unnatural links is penguin not panda....

Comment: Penguin, Panda, Platypus, Pumpkins.  It's all the same in the end - loss of traffic.